# How to add a new screen resolution for nVidia?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, nvidia, display

How can I add more screen resolutions to Thinkpad (W510) LCD?
I want to clone the external display which has a bit different sets of resolutions. The best resolution that is **common** to both displays is quite low.

In the past I used to have an ATI card so I used **xrandr** to add a new resolution, but somehow it does not work for my new machine which uses nVidia.

hints anyone ?

I'm using a very simple (default) xorg.conf file:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Device"
    Driver  "nvidia"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2):

Have tried System -> Administration -> Addition Drivers this will also install custom software for Nvidia graphics cards.

Under the screen section in xorg.conf try adding:

```
Section "Screen"
    ...
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Virtual     xdim ydim #your resolution x, y
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: did that already. I do have nvidia-settings  app. but I can't add new resolution (1600x1200).

Comment: @Yonatan you can define it manualy, can you send an output of your xorg.conf

Comment: I'm using a very simple (default) xorg.conf (see my questions for its content)

Comment: @Yonatan let me know if the additional entry had any result.

Comment: my LCD (thikpad) has 1600x900 while my external CRT display has 1600x1200. I wish both of them to clone same screen of 1600x1200. is that possible ? I don't want to have panning or something like that

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
 Example 11.1. Screen Section of the File /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Section "Screen" 
  DefaultDepth 16 
  SubSection "Display" 
    Depth 16
    Modes "1152x864" "1024x768" "800x600" 
    Virtual 1152x864 
  EndSubSection
  SubSection "Display" 
    Depth 24 Modes "1280x1024" 
  EndSubSection
  SubSection "Display" 
    Depth 32 Modes "640x480" 
  EndSubSection 
  SubSection "Display" 
    Depth 8 Modes "1280x1024" 
  EndSubSection 
  Device "Device[0]" 
  Identifier "Screen[0]" 
  Monitor "Monitor[0]" 
EndSection
```

Found here:

http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/suse/suse9.3/suselinux-adminguide_en/sec.x11.optimieren.html
I once was told to be careful not to set a higher resolution than monitor capability since that could cause hardware damage.